# How do I map a domain name to a full name in windows

Tags: windows, hostname

I have some links that are generated in a foreign unit of our company and do no list the full fully qualified domain name(I guess it works over there), just the hostname, can I map the hostname to the fqdn(in windows)?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing around with the `hosts` file located at `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (no file extension, open in notepad). You could do something like this:

```
# IP Address       hostname
192.168.12.12      otherdepthost
192.168.12.12      otherdepthost.fqdn
.
.
.
```

You'll have to get the IP addresses and modify the file if the IP addresses change. This method gives you the benefit of not needing to modify the files they give you since the having just the bare hostname will work on your machine.